# Arch Linux login password?

Tags: archlinux

I'm trying to login to a freshly installed Arch Linux but it doesn't accept my password. I've tried 'pi' as username and 'raspberry' as password. Any ideas what the password could be?

Comment: for standard user : alarm/alarm
and then root/root [yet another guide (github)](https://github.com/phortx/Raspberry-Pi-Setup-Guide)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

root/root

See [here](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi): "The default root password is 'root'."

Comment: @joan while the password is still valid the link does not cover arch linux anylonger.